# NLTK not working on iPython

Tags: ipython, nltk, package

I'm working with MacOS, I've installed Python and iPython, but when I type:

```
import nltk
```

ipython tells me that there is no module named `nltk`. However, when I type in:

```
import sys 

import nltk
```

It works perfectly fine. Can someone explain why this isn't working correctly? I'm a newbie to Python so please be gentle. Thanks.

Comment: What you describe makes no sense. Importing `sys` cannot affect the availability of the nltk. But maybe you have two versions of python; please **edit your questoin** and describe how you "installed Python and iPython". Did you know OS X already comes with Python 2?

Comment: So I did know that OSX comes with Python 2. I currently have both Python 2 and 3, as well as iPython. Python 3 and iPython both have this problem, while Python 2 seems to work perfectly fine. My thought is that the issue lies in my PYTHONPATH but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: I did figure it out. Embarrassingly all I had to do was reinstall pip3 and use it to install nltk for Python 3